# Google Play. Publish status: Rejected

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console

My app rejected by Google Play 3 times.
This is mail that they sent me:
[image]

In previous versions of the app, there were some permissions that I didn't request, I thought that was a problem and deleted those permissions and resubmitted the app and again I got rejected

My app asked to set the app as the Default Phone after signing up and if the user didn't set the app as the Default Phone, the app asked for some permissions.
This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.XXXX.Light"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".AuthActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|density"
            android:exported="false"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<!--        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />-->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/primary" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

        <service
            android:name=".core.service.AppFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".core.service.CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In main they wrote that app "Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app"
but the app needs all permissions.
 - this permission need to connect with the backend
 - this one is for reading contacts and showing to user
 - this one is for adding new contacts this is also app functionality
 - this one is for reading calls and showing to the user
 - this one is for get images from gallery and setting to avatar
 - and this one for call from app

What is a problem, can someone help me?

Comment: Are you really need CallReceiver and CallLogs permission?  If no delete it and submit again.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can re request the review with explaining all the use cases for all the permissions. Also check that you have selected that correct category in the Google play console in the app description(Maybe select something similar to Phone dialier)

I also found one issus in the manifest file is that it uses `usesCleartextTraffic` which transports says that app uses http API which is not encrypted in transit. Since you are dealing with lots of sensitive data yoi should also remove that flag